# Using CASE within a stored procedure Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use CASE WHEN within a stored procedure to return day name with a dow parameter and i get an error about an invalid syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ReturnWeekName(weekno double precision)
RETURNS  varchar AS $$

DECLARE 
     weekname varchar;
BEGIN

    CASE 
        WHEN weekno = 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN weekno = 1 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN weekno = 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN weekno = 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN weekno = 4 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN weekno = 5 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN weekno = 6 THEN 'Saturday'
    END AS weekname

    END;
    $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
Error: 
*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'Sunday'"
LINE 9:   WHEN weekno = 0 THEN 'Sunday'
                               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 158*
```

Comment: I find the names highly confusing. A parameter named `weekno` for something that represents the "day of the week" and a function named `ReturnWeekName` that returns the name of a day. Note that if you have a `date` or `timestamp` value, you can use the built-in function `to_char()` to get the name of the week day.

Comment: Yes thanks for this also. i actually wanted to use the case statement within a procedure and looked at this scenario. TO_CHAR(time as timstamp , 'Day') was also sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the CASE expression to the variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ReturnWeekName(weekno double precision)
RETURNS  varchar AS $$

DECLARE 
     weekname varchar;
BEGIN

    weekname := CASE 
        WHEN weekno = 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN weekno = 1 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN weekno = 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN weekno = 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN weekno = 4 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN weekno = 5 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN weekno = 6 THEN 'Saturday'
    END;
    return weekname;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or a bit simpler using a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ReturnWeekName(weekno double precision)
RETURNS  varchar AS $$
  SELECT CASE 
        WHEN weekno = 0 THEN 'Sunday'
        WHEN weekno = 1 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN weekno = 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
        WHEN weekno = 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
        WHEN weekno = 4 THEN 'Thursday'
        WHEN weekno = 5 THEN 'Friday'
        WHEN weekno = 6 THEN 'Saturday'
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```